# Scala object from Java factory function

Tags: scala, factory-pattern

I have a Java factory function `factoryFunction(String)`. In Scala I want to initialise a (singleton) object with the return from this function. The best I can manage is

```
object outer {
  val inner = factoryFunction("SOME_CONSTANT")
}
```

But if I do this I will end up referring to `outer.inner` every time I want to refer to the object, which is a little cumbersome. Is there any way of directly initialising `outer` with the result of the factory function?

One workaround I have thought of is to use a package object -- but that also feels awkward as I would end up with a proliferation of package objects, which is a little hard to manage.

Comment: `package objet pkg { val outer = FN }` btw dont see thé benefit

Comment: you want to encapsulate a factory method ?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @dmitry I was wondering if it was possible to write something like `object outer { this = factoryFunction(...) }` ... or something similar I couldn't find the syntax for.

Comment: Look like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why singleton object? You can initialize a value or lazy value just fine.

Comment: Are you aware that in Scala you can import not only packages but objects as well? Such as `import com.example.outer._`.

Comment: You don't need to "end up with a proliferation of package objects".  A single package can have many different things in it.

Comment: One more way to avoid referencing the outer object while accessing to the inner: create implicit function, import it, use it: `implicit def outer2inner(obj: outer.type): ObjectReturnedByTheFactory = outer.inner;    outer.anyAccessibleMemberOfTheObjectReturnedByTheFactory`